# find string of arbitrary length before a known string

Tags: python, string, parsing

Just say I have a string such as:

```
Lecture/NNP/B-NP/O delivered/VBD/B-VP/O at/IN/B-PP/B-PNP the/DT/B-NP/I-PNP UNESCO/NNP/I-NP/I-PNP House/NNP/I-NP/I-PNP in/IN/B-PP/B-PNP Paris/NNP-LOC/B-NP/I-PNP
```

I want to pull out every word which occurs before "/NNP/". This would mean my output is

> > Lecture, UNESCO, House

I tried:

print re.findall(r'/NNP/',string) then working backwards but I can't make it arbitrary. There is always a blank space leading the word which might help.

Edit: removed error in list.

Comment: How is `Paris` part of your answer, its not preceding `/NNP/` but rather `/NNP-`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = 'Lecture/NNP/B-NP/O delivered/VBD/B-VP/O at/IN/B-PP/B-PNP the/DT/B-NP/I-PNP UNESCO/NNP/I-NP/I-PNP House/NNP/I-NP/I-PNP in/IN/B-PP/B-PNP Paris/NNP-LOC/B-NP/I-PNP'

re.findall(r'(\S+)/NNP/', s)
=> ['Lecture', 'UNESCO', 'House']
```

Comment: +1 Almost exactly what I wrote but it's better to use `\S` over `[^\s]`.

Comment: Thanks. But for another area I get: [u'Erwin', u'Schr\xf6dinger', u'Bose\u2013Einstein', u'Quantizing', u'Erwin', u'Schr\xf6dinger', u'Schr\xf6dinger', u'Einstein', u'Einstein'] and when I do str() over that: for item in listout: print str(item). UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128). I know it is a long dash, but is there a way for this to appear in the terminal?

Comment: @Griff that should be a different question, but here goes :) : `print str(item.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: I tip my hat you sir! Thank-you.

Answer (score 2):

Forward lookahead.

```
>>> re.findall('(?:\s|^)[^/]+(?=/NNP/)', 'Lecture/NNP/B-NP/O delivered/VBD/B-VP/O at/IN/B-PP/B-PNP the/DT/B-NP/I-PNP UNESCO/NNP/I-NP/I-PNP House/NNP/I-NP/I-PNP in/IN/B-PP/B-PNP Paris/NNP-LOC/B-NP/I-PNP')
['Lecture', 'UNESCO', 'House']
```